# editing the host name in Linux

Tags: linux, editing, hostname

I needed to install some libraries (like libSM.i686) on my machine to be able to work with ANSYS Workbench (which is a fluid dynamic simulation software) and I encountered a problem in using the command yum install, like: "Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository":

This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.

```
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6Workstation/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
```

so I searched and realized that I have to change the hostname (from the [customer portal of ansys](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/373953)); I tried to change this file `/etc/sysconfig/network` ; I did so once by changing the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` in gedit and then saving it.

Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, so now I need to go back to the previous host name (which was in the form fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) in the format hostname.domainname). But now, surprisingly it doesn't allow me to do it any more. So I tried the command for editing the host name `cd /etc/sysconfig; vi network` but don't know how I should save the change I made in host name.

Answer (score 2):

tldr;

At the terminal, type the following command to open the hosts file:

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

Your hosts file will look like so:

[image]

rename the entry labeled with 127.0.1.1 with the hostname you prefer.
Back at the terminal, type the following command to open the hostname file:

> sudo nano /etc/hostname

This file only contains your current hostname:
Replace the default hostname with the same hostname you put in the previous step.save it.

Finally, we need to commit the changes to the system and reboot the system for the changes to take effect. At the terminal, enter the following command to commit the changes:

> sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh

Follow that command with:

> sudo reboot

Once the system comes back online your new hostname will be in effect.

full article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/167195/how-to-change-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-devices-hostname/).

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/sysconfig/network:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=hostname.domainname
```

The above will require a restart.

Change hostname without restart:

```
sysctl kernel.hostname=hostname.domainname
```

Use both to keep the changes if you restart later.