# Where does bash get its hostname data to set HOSTNAME and how can I change it permanently?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, hostname

I know that you can do something like this:

`export HOSTNAME=xyz`

`echo $HOSTNAME`

And you will see the changes made. However, where does bash read from on startup to set this environment variable? I know that you can of course write the export statement in `.bashrc`, but this seems more of a workaround than an actual solution.

I have also tried editing `/etc/hosts`, but the changes made do no survive a reboot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [editing the host name in Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/649260/editing-the-host-name-in-linux) Don't forget the `sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh`

Comment: I did not made changes in `/etc/hostname`, that was the problem. I also do not have `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from your distribution: you can do in 3 steps

1. Edit the *hostname-file* of your distribution (see below)

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hostname
   ```
2. Give the commands:

   ```
   sudo hostname YOUR_NEW_HOSTNAME  # to change it for this session  
   hostname                         # just to check it
   ```
3. After the edit the file `/etc/hosts`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hosts
   ```

**Debian/Ubuntu**
You need to edit the file `/etc/hostname`:
substitute the actual name with the new one.

**Slackware**  **Suse and Opensuse**
The file to edit is `/etc/HOSTNAME`:
substitute the actual name with the new one.

**Redhat,CentOS, Fedora**
The file to edit is `/etc/sysconfig/network`:
you have to substitute the name in the line where you find `HOSTNAME=OldName.OldDomain`

Note: if you are not in the *sudoers* you can gain root privilege, e.g with `su -`, and after give the same commands without `sudo`.

---

On some (maybe old)  **Debian** distribution based is used `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`
at the boot time where it is written  `/etc/hostname oldname`. To make it effective you have to change there too.

---

For a solution valid till the next reboot you can use `hostname newname`.
Probably it will not appear in your current shell because the variables are set on opening (you can fix it manually or working in a new shell).

From `man hostname` in the section  **SET NAME**

> When called with one argument or with the --file option, the commands set the host name  or  the  NIS/YP  domain
>          name.  hostname uses the sethostname(2) function, while all of the three domainname, ypdomainname and nisdomain‐
>          name use setdomainname(2).  Note, that this is effective only until the next  reboot.   **Edit  /etc/hostname  for
>          permanent change.**